# Java heap space error at large files with string.split

Tags: java, file, heap-memory, space

I have in the line a heap space error on an another machine, but it runs on my machine
I can't chance the properties of the another machine.
How can I solve this problem without using
Scanner.java ?

Is the argument of string.split correct with " " for split after spaces to split the String in pieces?

[File:]

```
U 1 234.003 30 40 50 true
T 2 234.003 10 60 40 false
Z 3 17234.003 30 40 50 true
M 4 0.500 30 40 50 true

/* 1000000+ lines */
```

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at java.base/java.util.Arrays.copyOfRange(Arrays.java:3821)
    at java.base/java.lang.StringLatin1.newString(StringLatin1.java:764)
    at java.base/java.lang.String.substring(String.java:1908)
    at java.base/java.lang.String.split(String.java:2326)
    at java.base/java.lang.String.split(String.java:2401)
    at project.FileR(Fimporter.java:99)
```

```
public static DataBase File(String filename) throws IOException {

   BufferedReader fs = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filename),64 * 1024);

   String line;
   String[] wrds;
   String A; int hash; double B; int C; int D; boolean E; DataBase DB = new DataBase();

   while (true) {

        line = fs.readLine();
        if (line == null) {break;}
        wrds = line.split(" ");     /* this is line 99 in the error-message */

        hash  = Integer.parseInt(wrds[1]); 
        B     = Double.parseDouble(wrds[2]);
        C     = Integer.parseInt(wrds[3]); 
        D     = Integer.parseInt(wrds[4]); 
        E     = Boolean.parseBoolean(wrds[5]); 

        // hash is hashcode for all values B C D E in DataBase DB

        DB.listB.put(hash,B);
        DB.listC.put(hash,C);
        DB.listD.put(hash,D);
        DB.listE.put(hash,E);

   }
```

Comment: From your code it doesn't look like the split is the problem but if you're keeping a lot of data in `DataBase` then that might cause the OOM. DId you set different memory constraints on the machines, e.g. via `-Xmx`? Did you take a heap dump and analyze it, e.g. with Eclipse MAT?

Comment: If the JVM on the other machine is in an X86 32 bit it may have only 1.4 to 1.6 GB of heap space at best. X64 is limited by the quantity of RAM in use.

Comment: @SamuelMarchant - that is true.  However, if the OP doesn't specify `-Xmx` at all, then the JVM will have the *default* max size which is typically a lot smaller than can be successfully requested using `-Xmx`.  (Besides, it is getting harder to find 32 bit machines in the wild these days ...)

Comment: @Stephan C Not many generic 32 bit, no, but if you want to install on many X64 computers the X32 kernel variants in Linux or older MS Win then 32 it is (period). It may also be dependent which JVM type 32 or 64 is on the other machine of even i will presume may these days simply be an X64 CPU , but that does not stop the machine having an x32(86 - i586) JVM , HOWEVER, good point if it is an X86 jvm binaries to bump up the heap size on the program command line * click-like - good point too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How can I solve this problem without using Scanner.java ?

`Scanner` is not the issue.

If you are getting OOME's with this code, the most likely root cause is the following:

```
DB.listB.put(hash,B);
DB.listC.put(hash,C);
DB.listD.put(hash,D);
DB.listE.put(hash,E);
```

You appear to loading all of your data into 4 maps.  (You haven't shown us the relevant code ... but I am making an educated guess here.)

My second guess is that your input files are very large, and the amount of memory needed to hold them *in the above data structures* is simply too large for the "other" machine's heap.

The fact that the OOME's are occurring in a `String.split` call is not indicative of a problem in `split` per se.  This is just the proverbial "straw that broke the camel's back".  The root cause of the problem is in what you are doing with the data after splitting it.

---

Possible solutions / workarounds:

1. Increase the heap size on the "other" machine.  If you haven't set the `-Xmx` or `-Xms` options, the JVM will use the default max heap size ... which is typically 1/4 of the physical memory.

   Read the [command documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/specs/man/java.html) for the `java` command to understand what `-Xmx` and `-Xms` do and how to set them.
2. Use more memory efficient data structures:

   - Create a class to represent a tuple consisting of B, C, D, E values.  Then replace the 4 maps with a map of these tuples.
   - Use a more memory efficient `Map` type.
   - Consider using a sorted array of tuples (including the hash) and using binary search to look them up.
3. Redesign your algorithms so that they don't need all of the data in memory at the same time; e.g. split the input into smaller files and process them separately.  (This may not be possible ....)

Answer (score 0):

If I'am not mistaken, you can allocate more heap-size when launching your jar file, e.g.:

```
java -Xmx256M -jar MyApp.jar
```

which means, you can change those settings.

But then again, just increasing the heap-size will not get rid of that problem, if the files get bigger, chances of oom increase.

You could think of splitting large files before processing like only process first X lines, then force GC to run (by nulling) and then process next lines.